# The x command does not correctly when invoked under SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager?

Tags: vba, sas

I have written some SAS code that calls R via the x command (I am using SAS 9.1.3 so there is no native SAS interface to R).

```
OPTIONS XWAIT XSYNC;
 X """&r_path."" --no-save --quiet < ""&out_code_folder.\code.r"" > ""&out_code_folder.\abba.log""";
```

This code works correctly when I run it in the SAS IDE but when I try to run the same code in VBA using (here strSAScode contains the above mentioned SAS code).

```
   Dim obWM As SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager
    Dim temp_dispaly_alert As Boolean
    Dim sm As SAS_Management    
    Debug.Print strSASCode    
    Set sm = New SAS_Management

    'Set obServerDef = New SASWorkspaceManagerServerDef
    Set obWM = New SASWorkspaceManager.WorkspaceManager
    Set obSAS = obWM.Workspaces.CreateWorkspaceByServer("MyServerName", VisibilityProcess, Nothing, "", "", "")
    Set sm.obLS = obSAS.LanguageService
    temp_dispaly_alert = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sm.obLS.Submit strSASCode
```

Now every other code works, except the x command. Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, use of SYSTEM and X commands is disabled when accessed via techniques that use integration technologies due to potential security risks.

Have you followed the steps for 9.1.3 on Windows described in [this](http://support.sas.com/kb/15/179.html) usage note?
It describes how to enable this functionality on your SAS server; you may need to adapt what's described for the *workspace*, instead of the *stored process*, server.